# How do I run a jQuery if statement on a function paremeter?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, if-statement, slick.js

I'm trying to avoid excessive code by simplifying my Slick Slider script. I'm trying to run a function that sets a boolean parameter but I'm obviously missing something here. The goal is to change the **fade** parameter from true to false if the .content-gallery has a .casestudy class, which is a different content type in my CMS.

Thanks!

```
$( window ).load(function() {
 var galleryStyle = true;
 var $gallerySlider = $("div.content-gallery-wrapper .content-gallery"),function(){
   if ( $gallerySlider.hasClass("casestudy") ) {
    var galleryStyle = false;
   } else {}
 };

 $gallerySlider.each(function(){
   $(this).slick({
      centerMode: true,
      centerPadding: '0',
      slidesToShow: 1,
      slidesToScroll: 1,
      // dots: true,
      prevArrow: '.arrow.left',
      nextArrow: '.arrow.right',
      fade: galleryStyle
    });
 });

 $('.loading').removeClass('loading');
});
```

Using one of the answers below, and moving the if statement into the initilization function seemed to take care of it.

```
$( window ).load(function() {
 var galleryStyle = true;
 var $gallerySlider = $("div.content-gallery-wrapper .content-gallery");

 $gallerySlider.each(function(){
    if ( $(this).hasClass("casestudy") ) {
        galleryStyle = false;
    }
 $(this).slick({
      centerMode: true,
      centerPadding: '0',
      slidesToShow: 1,
      slidesToScroll: 1,
      // dots: true,
      prevArrow: '.arrow.left',
      nextArrow: '.arrow.right',
      fade: galleryStyle
    });
});

$('.loading').removeClass('loading');
});
```

Comment: That code with the comma is weird; what is it that you expect that to do? (It's almost certainly not doing whatever that is, but it's too confusing to know what your intention is.)

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified that. I edited my question. The "fade" parameter controls whether the slider is fade (true), or slide (false). I want all galleries to be fade: true unless they are casestudy galleries, which have a .casestudy added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* that you want code that finds that "gallery" element and then sets the "galleryStyle" flag. That should be something like this:

```
var $gallerySlider = $("div.content-gallery-wrapper .content-gallery");
if ( $gallerySlider.hasClass("casestudy") ) {
    galleryStyle = false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this cleared up the error, but it looks like it's setting false to all sliders on the page whether they have casestudy or not. Does the flag have to be in the function that initializes the function? I'm assuming since it's find at least one casestudy, the script is setting the flag to false, then all sliders get initialized with fade: false.

Comment: Thank you your answer worked, I ended up moving the if statement into to initialization function.